# View of document library from the parent site on the child site

Tags: list-view, library, connection

I am using SharePoint 2016 online version. The scenario is

I have built a parent site called 'Project Home' which has a library 'All Projects Documents'.
There are three different child site: Project 1, Project 2, Project3. All have three own libraries. We want to sync all the documents from three child site with parent site.
Or
Is there any way to store all the documents in parent site library and bring views from parent site to show in child sites?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you place the parent library on web part page set with the view you want, you can export that view. The option to export should be in the dropdown that allows you to edit the web part. You can the upload it to the web part gallery.

Comment: Thank you very much for giving me a quick response, really apperciate. I believe that there is no option in the dropdown menu to export.